# Referencing through foreign key from different table

Tags: database, oracle, foreign-keys

I have a table T1 which I want to split into two tables, T2 and T3. The table T2 contains an id and distinct names from T1. I want to insert data into T3 which has a field id which is foreign key for id in T2. Now, when I take the data for T3 from T1 it gives me name but I want the column to have the corresponding id from T2.

e.g. t2 is

```
           1 | John
           2 | Jack
           3 | Jasper
```

now a record from t1 to t3 is

```
101 | +9038302873 | John | 200
102 | +9023757583 | Jack | 500
```

Now I want 1 in the above table instead of John and 2 instead of Jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given these tables ...

```
SQL> select * from t1;

        ID PHONE                NAME           SALARY
---------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
       101 +9038302873          John              200
       102 +9023757583          Jack              500

SQL> select * from t2:

   NAME_ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 John
         2 Jack
         3 Jasper

SQL> select * from t3;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

... we can populate T3 with a join on T1 and T2 like this:

```
SQL> insert into t3
  2      ( id, phone, name_id, salary)
  3  select t1.id
  4          , t1.phone
  5          , t2.name_id
  6          , t1.salary
  7  from t1
  8       join t2
  9          on t1.name = t2.name
 10  /

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from t3;

        ID PHONE                   NAME_ID     SALARY
---------- -------------------- ---------- ----------
       101 +9038302873                   1        200
       102 +9023757583                   2        500

SQL>
```

Note: you did not describe your tables so I have improvised column names. You will need to edit the INSERT statement to fit your schema.

Comment: hey.. can you help me in this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541100/fetch-table-name-from-a-column-for-from-clause